# How to bind a value in a component to an element in App.vue?

Tags: vue.js

I would like to bind a class to an element in App.vue, from a property or value in each page component. Kinda the opposite of passing a prop? Not exactly chld -> parent, definitely not parent -> child. I'm trying to use the route param but so far I can only get the value to bind to  with a refresh. Is there a fix for this approach or a better, vue way to do this?

App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <app-header />
        <main> ... <!-- objective: <main :class="[ get a value from each component loaded into router-view ]"> -->
            <router-view />
        </main>

    </div>
</template>


<script>

    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                name: 'App',
                mainClass: "", // update this value per route component
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            // console.log("this.$routes.params.id", this.$route.params.id); // undefined
            this.mainClass = this.$route.name.toLowerCase(); // √
        }
    }

</script>
```

gallery.vue:

```
<script>

    import Gallery from '../../data/Gallery.json';

    export default {
        name: 'Gallery',
        data () {
            return {
                h1: 'Gallery',
                Gallery: Gallery,
                objID: "",
                mainClass: ""
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            var Gallery = require('../../data/Gallery.json');
            for (let key in Gallery) {
                Gallery[key].id = key;
                !this.objID ? this.objID = key : ""
            }
        }, // created
        methods: {
            setFeaturedImage: function(objID) {
                this.objID = objID;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a computed property for that

```
   computed: {
        mainClass: function() {
            return this.$route.name.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. Once I got some clarity with both your and sovalina 's solution, I realized I had a new problem: how to set the mainClass at the domain. I wasn't able to solve that using the watcher, but I did succeed using the computed method:

 computed: {
  mainClass: function() {
   let name = this.$route.name;
   name = (name == "Index") ? "Gallery" : name;
   return name.toLowerCase();
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can use a watcher in your main App.vue.
Assuming your css classes have the same name of your routes, return a `mainClass` data (not computed because it's not a setter) and watch the route.name :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <main :class="mainClass">
      ...
    </main>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  data() {
    return {
      mainClass: ""
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route.name': function(name) {
      this.mainClass = name
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Please see my comment on phoet 's solution as to why I preferred it for my objective.